# Content Search Web Part Slider issue

Tags: content-search-web-part, content-srch-slider, webpart-width

I have created a  content search slider web part on my site's home page which acts as a nice looking slider that pulls images from a picture library.

But am facing an issue, even though I have adjusted the width and height of the images/content search web part, images are not occupying full space.

How do I adjust this web part such that, those images occupy full real estate and have these sliders in a full fledged manner.

[image]

[image]
As shown in the above figure, I want to fill the emptied space on the right hand side with the image.

Why I am on insisting on this look n feel, because after giving a demo of this landing page to my managers, they have told me either remove this slider or have these images occupy full space and scrolling from right to left, like many of Internet sites' landing pages.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with SharePoint. These image dimensions are not for your screen ration, if you **stretch** them they will look bad, if you make the width 100% it will chop of (about) 50% of the bottom.

Comment: that's correct. I tried to stretch and it looked bad. So, can you please help, how to adjust them?

Comment: Have you looked in to using Image Renditions?

Comment: no, I have yet to explore the image renditions. Let me see and update here.

Comment: Hire a graphic designer who understands (digital) images

Comment: Danny, can You pls stop answering my questions. That would be of great help. I hope someone else know  answers as well.

Comment: I believe the slider web part you're using now has fixed width. Look for a responsive image slider. There are few examples that are built using Content By Search, use Bootstrap.